# SSL Handshake in Android via Bluetooth Classic

Tags: android, tls1.2, android-bluetooth

I am looking to implement the SSL handshake via bluetooth classic in android for security purposes.
I was able to create SSLSocketFactory and SSLSocket from it, but unable to add it to the BluetoothSocket.
Was using API Level 29 and Android 11.
Can anyone help me out please. Appreciate the response.

I would like to accomplish the same logic like in the github link https://github.com/AntonFagerberg/2-Way-SSL-Java-Demo/blob/master/src/Client.java

Instead of Http/Https, I would like to use Bluetooth Classic as the communication medium.

Please find the code implemented

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
 @SuppressLint("Assert")
 ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
 bluetoothDevice = device;
 try {
   bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
   Log.d( TAG, "Trying to open the socket to " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress() );
   String privateMethod = "createRfcommSocket";
   Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod( privateMethod, int.class );
   bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke( bluetoothDevice, 1 );
   assert bluetoothSocket != null;
   bluetoothSocket.connect(); // socket opened successfully
   Log.d( TAG, "bluetoothSocket: "+  bluetoothSocket.isConnected() );
 } catch ( Exception connectException ) {
    // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
    try {
      Log.d( TAG, "connectException: "+connectException );
      if( bluetoothSocket != null ) {
         bluetoothSocket.close();
      }
     } catch (IOException closeException) {
       Log.e( TAG, "Could not close the client socket: " + closeException );
     }
     return;
     } finally {
       try {
         if( bluetoothSocket != null ) {
             bluetoothSocket.close();
         }
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }

@SuppressLint("Assert")
    public void run() {
        InputStream mInputStream = null;
        OutputStream mOutputStream = null;
            try {
                // DO THE SSL HANDSHAKE HERE AND THEN WRITE DATA TO SERVER USING OUTPUT STREAM

                TlsSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = new TlsSocketFactory();
                SSLContext sslContext = tlsSocketFactory.getSSLContext(getApplicationContext());
                
                // How to convert a BluetoothSocket to Socket to make handshake successful
                Socket socket = new Socket( bluetoothDevice.getAddress(), 1 );
                SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, null, 1 ,false);

                sslsocket.setUseClientMode( true );
                sslsocket.startHandshake();

                Log.d(TAG, "SSL Handshake Successful");

                try {
                    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( sslsocket.getInputStream() ) );
                    String response = null;
                    while ((response = read.readLine()) != null)
                        Log.d( TAG, response );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
                }

                String outputString = "appdata";
                Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
                byte[] byteArray = outputString.getBytes(charset);

                mOutputStream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
                mOutputStream.write(byteArray);
                mOutputStream.flush();

                Log.d(TAG, "bluetoothDevice.getBondState(): " + bluetoothDevice.getBondState() + ",bluetoothSocket.isConnected(): " + bluetoothSocket.isConnected() );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e );
                    assert false;
                    if( mInputStream != null )
                        mInputStream.close();
                    assert false;
                    if( mOutputStream != null )
                        mOutputStream.close();
                    if( bluetoothSocket != null )
                        bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    closeException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can add any code snippets or configuration that you've already tried, that will go a long way towards getting someone to give you a valuable answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to know whether we can do SSL Handshake using Bluetooth socket in android. I have a client program written in C which authenticates with the Server (Telematics device) using bluetooth classic. Don't have access to server source code. Need to implement the same in Android Mobile App using Java.

Comment: Have you added security config in the android manifest file? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config